# Jenkins merge branch after approval

Tags: github, jenkins

We have a declarative pipeline in Jenkins which pulls code, runs some tests and then has a manual approval stage. If the manual approval stage is approved I'd like the pipeline to merge the branch into master and then deploy from master.

I'm struggling to get a git merge working in a Jenkins declarative pipeline. This is what I have for the approval and merge stages:

```
        stage('Approval') {
            steps {
                snsPublish(topicArn:"${SNS_TOPIC_ARN}", subject:"Approval Needed: ${env.JOB_NAME}", message:"Jenkins IAM job '${env.JOB_NAME} [${env.BUILD_NUMBER}] requires your approval.\n\nClick below to view the job.\n\n${env.BUILD_URL}", messageAttributes: ['k1': 'v1', 'k2': 'v2'])
                script {
                    timeout(time: 1, unit: 'HOURS') {
                        approval = input message: 'Please approve for deployment', ok: 'Submit', parameters: [choice(choices: ['Approve', 'Reject'], name: 'APPROVAL_STATUS')],submitter: 'admin',submitterParameter: 'approverID'
                    }
                }
                echo "Approval status: ${approval}"
            }
        }

        stage('Git Merge') {
            when {
                expression { approval["APPROVAL_STATUS"] == 'Approve' }
            }
            environment {
                GIT_AUTHOR_NAME = "git"
            }
            steps {
                withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'github-app-jenkins', usernameVariable: 'GITHUB_APP', passwordVariable: 'GITHUB_ACCESS_TOKEN' )]){
                    sh '''
                        git fetch --all
                        git checkout master
                        git merge ${GIT_BRANCH}
                        '''
                }
            }
        }
```

But this fails with the error

```
git fetch --all
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.**********.com': No such device or address
```

Any suggestions on how I might achieve a merge after approval?

Comment: `No such device or address` this means your git config is messed. GitHub URL is incorrect. Run command - `git config --list` and check for `remote.origin.url`